# Choosing towns with largest area with exact amount of inhabitants

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have polygon layer of Villages and I have to choose an area of Villages as large as possible that have (together) the same amount of inhabitants as the largest one.

Basically, I need to create a layer of Villages with area large as possible and with same amount of inhabitants as the Capital.

Now I see that i need to use "knapsack problem" but I'm not skilled in Python. Is there a method in ArcMap (model or something) that can solve this?

Comment: This is essentially the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: I don't use ArcGIS, but I would think you could convert this [SO answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20569/dynamic-programming-solution-to-knapsack-problem) from Python.

Comment: Yes like the `knapsack` problem as mentioned in Wikipedia, area is like bucks and count of the inhabitant in the capital is like the constraint weight here. Using arcpy cursor it can be done easily.

Comment: Yes knapsack problem seems to be what i want. But I'm quite unskilled in python. Do you have any examples of applying knapsack problem into ArcMap?